# SQL query to average values only if more than one value, not equal to 0, exits?

Tags: mysql, sql

I only want to calculate an AVG of values if two or more non-zero values exist for a specific item_id. If two or more non-zero values do not exist, I do not want to calculate the AVG.

The current SQL is below.  Perhaps there should be an if clause first?...  any ideas?

```
SELECT AVG( days_since ) AS days_out
  FROM (
    SELECT days_since
    FROM user_123
    WHERE item_id = 645
AND days_since <> 0
ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
  ) AS recent
```

Seems like an If clause might work;

```
IF SELECT COUNT (*), item_id, days_since >= 2 
where days_since <>0, then perform AVG...
```

Comment: What do you want it to produce instead of an average?  No rows of data at all?

Comment: great question; don't want to produce anything if there are less than two non-zero records for a particular item_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT AVG(days_since) AS days_out
  FROM User_123
 WHERE Item_ID = 645
   AND Days_Since <> 0
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I'm not sure what the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses are for, so you'll have to adapt the answer to reimpose the conditions implied by them.

---

> How to keep it working while reapplying Order By and Limit. These are used so that only the 5 most recent entries are used in the Average calculation.

```
SELECT AVG(days_since) AS days_out
  FROM (SELECT days_since
          FROM User_123
         WHERE Item_ID = 645
           AND Days_Since <> 0
         ORDER BY ID DESC
         LIMIT 5
       ) AS u
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks, the query you suggested works! now to figure out how to keep it working while reapplying Order By and Limit.  These are used so that only the 5 most recent entries are used in the Average calculation.